# Failed to execute child process "/usr/libexec/gvfsd-trash" (No such file or directory)

Tags: 22.04, trash, gvfs

When click on the icon from the file manager, I get this error. I am on Ubuntu 22.04.3.

Tried to reinstall gvfs with `sudo apt install --reinstall gvfs` and reboot but no changes. The file doesn't exist in /usr/libexec/ along with other gvfs files.

Let me know if any logs would be helpful to solve this issue, will be happy to provide.

Comment: `/usr/libexec/gvfsd-trash` appears to be provided by the [gvfs-daemons](https://packages.ubuntu.com/jammy/amd64/gvfs-daemons/filelist) package

Comment: I tried the reinstall of gvfs, it didn't work. Should i download some deb package and install from that?

Comment: Did you try the reinstall of `gvfs-daemons` specifically, or just of `gvfs`?

Comment: @steeldriver thanks! I had just done gvfs, when did a reinstall of gvfs-deamon it worked!

Answer (score 1):

On performing a re-install of gvfs-deamons specifically as suggested by @steeldriver in the comments, it started working.

```
sudo apt-get reinstall gvfs-daemons
```